# the requirement of T for vector<T> used in default initialization

Tags: c++, c++14

`vector<const int>()` fails to compile in C++14 (and in C++03).

Under C++03, we can say `const int` is not `CopyAssignable`, so naturally it fails.
However, under C++14, the wording in the standard is the requirement of `T` given `vector<T>()` depends on the relevant operation.

I searched the cppreference and the isoc++14 for the corresponding part, but didn't find the reason why `const int` fails here.

My question is, where in the standard mentions the requirement of `T` given `vector<T>()`?

Comment: Have linked to an answer for C++11 -- AFAIK nothing changed between C++11 and C++14

Comment: @M.M the last comment there says it's located under the allocator requirement, I checked the c++14 standard, there is no such clause as menetioned by that comment.

Comment: I'll see if I can add an answer to the other thread that includes the relevant references  (and noting any changes between C++11 and C++14). The allocator parts are tough reading

Comment: @M.M magically enough, the one posted on year 2011 just updated that thread.

Comment: Fantastic, looks like Mr. Hinnant finally transferred his comment to an answer as suggested :)